# How to use version 8 default.nb style sheet in place of version 9 default.nb

Tags: stylesheet, installation

I do not like the new default.nb style sheet in version 9, and would like to use the older one that was used in version 8 for any new notebook and for any notebook created since I started using V9.

I saw in the `StyleSheets` folder that V8 default.nb is still there

[image]

So I went to preferences and changed the following to say `Default_8.0.nb`

[image]

And restarted Mathematica. Now when I open a new notebook, it seems to be Default_8.0.nb since `Section` headers are in black and text font is times new Roman. So I thought that is good. Problem fixed. (even thought the Style sheet Default does not have the *check* mark on next to the it, so I am worried I need to do something more)

[image]

However, when I opened an existing notebook that I made some changes in since V9 was installed, I noticed that it still  using V9 default.nb. Even though the Style sheet says `Default`.

[image]

*Question is* What is the correct and recommended steps to use Version 8 default.nb in version 9, so that any notebook that was used version 9 default.nb will now automatically use `Default.8.0.nb`

(I really do not understand how can WRI make this change for users without asking them. I do not want someone changing the style sheet of my documents without at least asking me. This should have an option for the user to decide on)

thanks

Comment: Did you not see the big prompt at the top of the window the first time you opened this notebook in version 9?

Comment: Yes - I agree ... the Mma 9 default stylesheets are appalling. The change of font from Times to Arial makes it look like it is designed for web teenies doing their nails, almost the opposite extreme from a professional math app. The new stylesheets also visually 'lose' structure compared to v8, making large complicated notebooks difficult to follow. The v8 defaults are far superior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `DefaultStyleDefinitions` only selects which style sheet to use for new Notebooks.  It does not actually change which sheet is represented by "Default" in the list.  This is why you see that item unchecked.

I believe you will need to replace the `Default.nb` *file* with the v8 version if you wish to force that behavior on existing Notebooks, but I don't know what you might break doing so.

Comment: After installing 9 is there also a core.nb and core_8.nb? If so if you replaced the default stylesheet in 9 with the one from 8 wouldn't it inherit from V9 core.nb?