# Fonts in Mathematica

Tags: fonts

Is there a font in Mathematica that corresponds to $$\Re$$ I found  `\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]` corresponds to [image: d]

But this is different to the R I have written in first.

Comment: Try: ` \[GothicCapitalR]` ; also see `\[ScriptCapitalR]`. Character codes are 8476 and 8475 respectively.

Comment: Nope... not quite.

Comment: I think so :( nothing is matching

Comment: In $\LaTeX$ it is Fraktur font, I believe, but *Mathematica* doesn't have it.  Try running this:  `Text[Style[R, 24, FontFamily -> #]] & /@ $FontFamilies` to see all the fonts.  Yep:  https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/07/21/fraktur-math/

Comment: I thought you were looking for a symbol in Mma that corresponded to the image of R shown. It is a gothic font and a half-matching font on my system is SWGothg font. Closest match in Mathematica to a gothic symbol is GothicCapitalR. Goto Palettes->Special Characters and see if it helps.

Comment: @Syed But it’s not matching exactly. I need an exact match

Comment: Give me an hour.

Comment: Thanks Syed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Evaluate: `FromCharacterCode[120189]`. Either something will show up in the output cell or not. Still go ahead and copy/paste the invisible output into MS word. Of course inside MS word, just type U1D57D and then press Alt-X to see if you like the font. Word has proper support for unicode chars > 65535. For a more detailed Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597013/reading-an-utf-8-encoded-text-file-in-mathematica. The unicode page for unicode equivalents of Fraktur is : https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/1D5.html. I am out of ideas now.

Comment: `Style["R", FontSize -> 46, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"]`?

Comment: @kglr, I downloaded and installed this font on Windows. It matches the picture above. I will wait till someone posts a detailed UTF tutorial to understand the topic better. My understanding is that the notebook will render symbols only when mma supports them and has a \\[...] name for them.

Comment: @kglr What I got is just a capital R!

Comment: @Syed I need to copy to lyx. Not MS word. It is not giving an output to lyx

Comment: What does *MS Word* have to do with anything?  I think you'll have to install a new font in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Are you able to use the Fraktur font in lyx indep. of Mma? It can't be used as a symbol in Mma. A UTF symbol appears without having to install any fonts on the OS. That is the idea and Mma seems to be lagging. MS word came in handy for the demo. What does it mean to install a font in a sware only? A sw should be able to use system fonts. See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/how-to-get-the-new-font-in-mathematica-10 . I would like to know how to install a font in Mma. But before I do that, I would like to know how to use a UTF char > 65535 in Mma first.

Comment: I modified Davis Stork's code to ````{Text[Style[R, 24, FontFamily -> #]], #} & /@ $FontFamilies```` so I could see what's what.  "SWGothg" looks very close: ````Style["R", FontSize -> 46, FontFamily -> "SWGothg"]````

Comment: use MaTex and then you can write anything in MMA that exists in LaTeX

Answer (score 1):

I think SWGothg is as close as I can get with fonts I have installed.
`Style["R", FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "SWGothg"]`

Requested: [image: Requested:]

SWGothg: [image]

Comment: Are you on Windows? SWGothg does not seem to be a "built-in" on my (Mac) system.

Comment: I don't have SWGothg on my Windows 10 Home system. From where it can be taken?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov https://bigfontsite.com/fonts/swgothg.html

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 21H1, Mathematica 12.3. I have not specifically installed any font packs, must have come with some other software I have installed (Maybe SolidWorks?)

Comment: In the comments under the main question, @kglr has already suggested the "Euclid Fraktur" font that is an exact match. I think the OP needs further help with the use of that font in LateX.